# Usort sort multidimensional array by duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
[0] => ['name' => John, city => NY, street => WallStreet ..some anouther fields]
[1] => ['name' => Bill, city => FI, street => smstr..  some anouther fields]
[2] => ['name' => John, city => NY, street => WallStreet  ..some anouther fields]
[3] => ['name' => Bill, city => FI, street => smstr ..some anouther fields]
[4] => ['name' => 4, city => 4, street => 4 ..some anouther fields]
```

I need to sort it to get all duplicate  name city and street fields to be on the top of array or just in sequence

what I want

```
[] => ['name' => John, city => NY, street => WallStreet..some anouther fields]
[] => ['name' => John, city => NY, street => WallStreet ..some anouther fields]
[] => ['name' => Bill, city => FI, street => smstr  ..some anouther fields]
[] => ['name' => Bill, city => FI, street => smstr ..some anouther fields]
[] => ['name' => 4, city => 4, street => 4 ..some anouther fields]
```

I'm trying use usort

```
 usort($sorted, function($a, $b) {
            if ($a['name'] == $b['name'] &&
              $a['city'] == $b['city'] &&
              $a['street'] == $b['street']
            ){
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        });
```

but it's does not work on php 5.3 , can anybody propose the solution?

p/s I'm working with php 5.3 :(

Comment: what is your expected outcome you want? paste that too in your question

Comment: What defines a duplicate? Does it have to be a duplicate of name AND city AND street, or any duplicate of any of those? And what do you mean by "on the top of array or just in sequence"?

Comment: Please try to include a slightly larger example of input, as well as an example of the output you're trying to get, and a clear explanation of _why_ that should be the output.

Comment: attach input and wanted output 
yes  duplicate matching only if  name AND city AND street a the same 
@Don'tPanic

Comment: Wow, that was quick! I'm not used to that type of response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map to an array imploding the values, sort that descending and sort the original by that array:

```
array_multisort(array_map(function($v) {
                              return implode('-', $v);
                          }, $array), 
                SORT_DESC, $array);
```

To break it out and understand the pieces:

```
// Build an array of the values in each sub array
// John-NY-WallStreet
$sorter = array_map(function($v) { return implode('-', $v); }, $array);
print_r($sorter);
// Sort that descending sorting the original array the same
array_multisort($sorter, SORT_DESC, $array);
```

This will work for all of the elements in the arrays. If for whatever reason you only want `name`, `city` and `street`, then replace the `return` with:

```
return $v['name'].'-'.$v['city'].'-'.$v['street'];
```

Comment: wow, it's working, I need time to understand how you did it) Thanks

Comment: Thanks, added a little description